# Pyephem RA & DEC to GHA & DEC

Tags: python, pyephem

In Pyephem is there a way to list Greenwich Siderial Time GST so that I can convert Right Ascension RA to Greenwich Hour Angle GHA?

```
>>>import ephem                                       
>>>j=ephem.Sun()                               
>>>j.compute('2018/11/10 23:00:00.0')                 
>>>print('%s %s' %  (j.ra, j.dec))                          
15:04:08.77  -17:19:41.4
```

I am using idle-python2.7, I am not familiar enough with Pyephem to determine where/when the first point of Aries is. With this I can convert ra-->gha. The above gives the ra/dec for the Sun for date/time shown

Comment: Could you show some example code? That would make it easier to see what exactly you need.

Comment: >>>import ephem                                       >>>j=ephem.Sun()                               >>>j.compute('2018/11/10 23:00:00.0')                 >>>print('%s %s' %  (j.ra, j.dec))                          15:04:08.77  -17:19:41.4                                                    I am using idle-python2.7, I am not familiar enough with Pyephem to determine where/when the first point of Aries is. With this I can convert ra-->gha. The above gives the ra/dec for the Sun for date/time shown. Thanks!

Comment: I found a post with a solution dec1st_2012_user 1867570, He created an object with RA=0deg and worked out the Greenwich Siderial Time GST from there. BR/JC

Comment: Thanks so much for finding that existing answer! I've edited its title to make it clearer, and used the "duplicate" button to create a link here.

Comment: I learned so much researching this! My basic motivation was to have an alternate source for getting GHA/RA other than the Nautical Almanac. I first tried using  the JPL Horizons web interface, but I found a huge difference in Sun DEC over the NA by about 29min. Then I used PyEphem and found the answer to my question on stack! I also found an earlier answer to why the DEC is different due to the nature of the "epoch" (Skyfield & Nautical Almanac 2016/7/23). I wonder if you can adjust JPL web to set this? Anyways thanks for the valuable info. BR/JC